# How to change the value of a model based on two form inputs using ASP.Net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have this class Recyclable Item

```
public class RecyclableItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RecyclableTypeId { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public decimal ComputedRate { get; set; }
    }
```

And a class for individual <select> options for another class RecyclableType

```
    public class RecyclableTypeOptions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    }
```

I used ViewData to send this list of RecyclableTypeOptions to the Create view of RecyclableItem

```
        // GET: RecyclableItem/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<RecyclableTypeOptions> options = PopulateOptions();
            ViewData["RecyclableTypeOptions"] = options;
            return View();
        }

        private List<RecyclableTypeOptions>  PopulateOptions()
        {
            List<RecyclableTypeOptions> options = _repoType.GetAllRecyclableTypesOptions();
            return options;
        }
```

My requirement is to autocompute `ComputedRate` by multiplying the Weight and Rate.

The solution I've been working on was:

1. Get Rate from the <select>
2. Read the form input for Weight
3. Multiply Weight and Rate
4. On change of either, update model.ComputedRate

But this has been *incredibly* difficult for me to accomplish. How exactly do I do this? Or whats the best way of doing this?

One alternative that I thought of was using foreign keys from the get go but I having a hard time wrapping my head around it. I'm using ASP.Net 4.8

Comment: "*But this has been incredibly difficult for me to accomplish. How exactly do I do this? Or whats the best way of doing this?*" Do you have code you can share of your attempt(s) at this?

Comment: If the `Rate` changes at some point in the future, do you wish for the `ComputedRate` to be updated. Or should it be fixed at the point the `RecyclableItem` is created? If it should be updated then you probably don't need to store it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what we need to do here is work out a little about what is going on and what you want to do. So You've laid out your Models and seem to have you database connection going - all good.

If you want to do a forign key then there are a few ways of doing this.

```
public class RecyclableItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RecyclableTypeOptionsId { get; set; }

        public vitual RecyclableTypeOptions RecyclableTypeOptions { get; set; }

        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public decimal ComputedRate { get; set; }
    }
```

In this first way I've changed the int to `RecyclableTypeOptionsId` and create a virtual element of `RecyclableTypeOptions`. When you add a new migration it should try and build in a foreign key. The RecyclableTypeOptions element is populated using `lazy loading` or `implicit loading` (using `Include`) - you might want to read on both.

Another option is (bit easier with what you have)

```
public class RecyclableItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RecyclableTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RecyclableTypeId ")]
        public virtual RecyclableTypeOptions RecyclableTypeOption { get; set; }


        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        public decimal ComputedRate { get; set; }
    }
```

In this example it's explict on what is the foreign key and you get the same virtual element.

Moving on, with regards the computed rate, well - this is down to you. You have basically 2 appraches.

**Approach 1.**

So like Tom says you might consider making calculating the rate on the fly - an example would be..

public class RecyclableItem
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public int RecyclableTypeOptionsId { get; set; }

```
    public vitual RecyclableTypeOptions RecyclableTypeOptions { get; set; }

    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? ComputedRate { get {
        if(RecyclableTypeOptions != null) {
            
           return Weight * RecyclableTypeOptions.Rate;
        }
        return null;
```

} }
}

**Approach 2**
In contrast you could always calculate the value in the View (Javascript) and return the result back and store that in your database.

Equally as valid is working it out in the controller (just incase you don't trust the use) and storing that as well.

--

On a side note your code uses ViewData and I would look at ViewModels (VMs) which are basically a new Class that you can create, send to the View and display the information on the page. Everything is more 'typed' and things like `@Html.TextBoxFor` functions easier. Also with those functions Unobtrusive validation from javascript kicks in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I had tunnel vision and tried to do it purely through C#. I used approach 2, made the "dynamic update" in the front-end then threw the result into the database.